# R: Creating more space between bars in geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a bar chart in R for values of a certain case over time, using geom_col. The chart contains values per week for a period of about a year and a half.

My problem with my current plot is that the bars are pretty close together. Especially in a PDF format, this creates a problem, since zoomed out it looks more like a histogram. You really have to zoom in drastically to see that the plot consists of individual bars per week. See below.

So what I've tried to do is increase the size between the bars, using `position = position_dodge(width=2))`. However, so far I see no changes. Why doesn't it take the position dodge? Because the x scale is based on dates?

Below is the `head()` of my df and a basic version of the code for the plot I'm trying to make.

```
structure(list(Land = c("India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
"India"), Date = structure(c(18498, 18491, 18484, 18477, 18470, 
18463), class = "Date"), SUMU = c(88L, 142L, 96L, 101L, 112L, 
128L), ChangeAVG = c("Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(Land = "India", 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(India, aes(Date, SUMU, fill=ChangeAVG))+ theme_light() + geom_col(position = position_dodge(width=10))
```

Examples of plot view in PDF normally and with zoom at 200%

[image: Zoom 115%]
[image: Zoom at 200%]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the width of the bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the width argument inside `position_dodge`. Move it outside that call:

```
ggplot(India, aes(Date, SUMU, fill=ChangeAVG)) + 
theme_light() + 
geom_col(width=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: That is my problem indeed. So to understand this a bit better: increasing the width between the bars actually has the same effect as decreasing the size of the the bars since the x-axis remains unchanged?

Is there a way to have the x axis take into account the extra space?